# Problem with list array/collection in easyadmin symfony doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, easyadmin

I have problem with vieving the list.
I need all of array not only counting.

CrudController:

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
    return [
        IdField::new('id')->hideOnForm()->hideOnDetail(),
        TextField::new('firstName','Imię'),
        TextField::new('lastName','Nazwisko'),
        AssociationField::new('specialization','Specjalizacja'),
        AssociationField::new('visits','Wizyty')->onlyOnDetail(),

    ];
}
```

FirstEntity:

```
/**
 * @var Visit[]|ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Visit", mappedBy="doctor")
 */
private $visits;
```

SecondEntity:

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Patient")
     * @var Patient
     */
    private $patient;
```

And the result:

[counting instead of displaying an array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fu0LS.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using AssociationField which works fine for a **one to many** relationship but only show count in a **many to one** relationship.

Use **ArrayField** instead.

See [field types](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/fields.html#field-types).

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
    return [
        IdField::new('id')->hideOnForm()->hideOnDetail(),
        TextField::new('firstName','Imię'),
        TextField::new('lastName','Nazwisko'),
        AssociationField::new('specialization','Specjalizacja'),
        ArrayField::new('visits','Wizyty')->onlyOnDetail(),

    ];
}
```